# Remove row click event from the first column in grid view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I created a grid view. Then i bound row click event which is applied to all of its rows.

Below is the code:-

```
Protected Sub DG1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles DG1.RowDataBound                                                                               
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='pointer';")
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:Call_Ajax('" & e.Row.DataItem("id") & "');")
End Sub
```

But i want to remove row click event from the first column(Edit column).

Thanks

Comment: Minor note... you don't need the `javascript:` prefix on event handlers.  (It is required when using script in the `href` of the `<a>` tag)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (so comment, rather than answer) but can you set a dummy `onclick="return false;"` to the first cell?  I think that will override the row's click handler

Comment: Where do you add the event handler? Note that you should use `RowType` to check if the current row is the header, footer or notmal `DataRow`.

Answer (score 1):

On the databound event you can remove the onclick attribute.

```
Private Sub DG1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DG1.DataBound
    dg1.Rows(0).Attributes.Remove("onclick")
End Sub
```